# What is Corgi mode on Google colab notebook?

Tags: google-colaboratory

What does the *Corgi Mode* do in Google Colaboratory?

Accessible from `Tools > Preferences`.

[image: Corgi mode on Google colab]

Comment: Currently accessed from Tools->Settings->Miscellaneous->Corgi Mode

Comment: I feel like, it is there because when you are into something, sitting back and thinking looking at the screen, it has the movements instead of the flat boring screen. We usually do some unconscious things such as nail biting, nose squeezing and other weird stuff while thinking, and the modes such as corgi mode keep our mind a little distracted but busy so that we can get some idea. And I have experienced its advantages multiple times.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The Corgi mode setting adds animated Corgis in the header.

[image]

https://twitter.com/GoogleColab/status/1116487177364365313

Answer (score 17):

There is also a Cat Mode now, so you can have a little more fun :)
[image: Walking cats]

Answer (score 6):

There is also a crab mode now, so you can have a full zoo running in your Colab header (:

[image: Screenshot having different easters]