# Get rid of dogs appearing in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

There are some annoying and distracting dogs appearing in my Google Colab window. How can I get rid of them? they look like Microsoft Office's 'Clippy' but in the dog version.

[image: Dogs photo]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Corgi mode on Google colab notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55652482/what-is-corgi-mode-on-google-colab-notebook)

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings in Top - Right Corner
go to Miscellaneous tab and uncheck all the boxes
set the power level to no power

click save

Hope this helps[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DDAD.png)